# How to create new file in Finder and open it?

Tags: file, applescript

For some reason Finder on Mac doesn't come with create new file functionality. The fastest way I've found to create a new file is to drag the finder path into Terminal and create a file there... which is super annoying

I wrote an apple script to automatically create a new file and bound it to a shortcut. It works perfectly, except that I can't figure out how to *open* the new file from within the applescript. I'm pretty sure the error stems from POSIX / UNIX paths but couldn't find a way to get this to work even when I put POSIX next to file, currentDir etc.

Here's my script:

```
set file_name to display dialog "File Name" default answer "untitled" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"
set file_name to (text returned of file_name)

tell application "Finder"
    set theWin to window 1
    set currentDir to POSIX path of (target of theWin as alias)
    
    make new file at (the target of the front window) as alias with properties {name:file_name}
    set currentPath to (currentDir & file_name) as string
    open file currentPath
end tell
```

The script creates the file, then errors out saying it can't find the file to open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned up the code a bit and got rid of unnecessary lines.

```
set fileName to text returned of (display dialog "File Name" default answer ¬
    "untitled" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2)

tell application "Finder" to set newFile to (make new file at Finder window 1 ¬
    with properties {name:fileName}) as alias

delay 0.1
do shell script "open -e " & quoted form of POSIX path of newFile
```

Note: If you're trying to use `open -a` instead of `open -e`... And you were getting error messages, try using `open -b`.  This option allows you to open the files with the application by using the application's bundle identifier to identify the application to use.

For example, if I want to open the files with **Visual Studio Code.app** by using it's  bundle identifier... The `do shell script` command would look like this...

```
do shell script "open -b com.microsoft.VSCode " & quoted form of POSIX path of newFile
```

If you do not know how to get the bundle identifier for the application to use when opening the file,  this following AppleScript code allows you to choose an application then copies it's bundle identifier to the clipboard.  Then just go back and paste that into the `do shell script "open -b "` command.

```
activate
set chosenApp to name of (choose application with title ¬
    "Choose App" with prompt "Choose App")
delay 0.1

tell application chosenApp to set appID to id

set the clipboard to appID
```

---

*Be sure to grant Terminal.app the appropriate permissions in System Prefs.*

Comment: Thx for your answer. I get the same permissions error as the other question. Tried setting accessibility for FastScript (how I'm running the workflow) but that didn't do anything. Files without file extensions the same as text files anyways on mac, so it's not a problem if it opens in script editor because I can change the default app. I want to be able to create shell files, python files etc.

Comment: @Alec  I updated the code in my post and tested with files created with no file extension and with file extensions ".txt" , ".sh" , ".py" and ".scpt". The `open -e` command ensures the files will open with TextEdit.app.  The command `man open` in Terminal shows the different options you can use with the `open` command.

Comment: perfect. do you know why adding & "-a Visual\ Studio\ Code.app" to the end and removing -e fails?

Comment: @Alec  I added some additional information to my post which may be a good work around for the error you get using the `open -a` command.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Do you know what the bundle identifier of VSCode is?

Comment: @Alec I added code to my post for you to be able to get the bundle identifier. It is `com.microsoft.VSCode`.  I installed  Visual Studio Code.app for testing and edited the `do shell script` command to this `do shell script "open -b com.microsoft.VSCode " & quoted form of POSIX path of newFile`.  It works on my system and the files open with  Visual Studio Code.app.

Comment: Why did you go through the trouble of using Finder to create the file, then call out to the shell to open the file ?  But then you describe the use of two different naming conventions as _bad practice_.  Where are you drawing your lines, exactly, and why don't any of your lines join up ?

Comment: @CJK Grasshoppa LOL.  The only reason I used Finder is because the OP's original code specifically targets for the new file to be created at `Finder window 1` and since we already targeted Finder... May as well continue on with Finder creating the actual file.  The next issue was that if the file which was created had no name extension, then the command for opening that file throws an error cause Finder doesn't know what to do with it. Since the new file file extensions could be nothing or .scpt or .py etc...  My thought, right off the bat, was the `do shell script open` command was perfect

Comment: The Finder stuff I'm good with. It's your shelling out that seemed off-piste, but I see your logic. The couple hundred times or so I advised using System Events for file operations wasn't wasted then. You do need to use Finder to access the front Finder window, i.e. `tell application "Finder" to set dir to the target of Finder window 1 as text`. But then you can `tell application "System Events" to tell (make new file at folder dir with properties {name:fileName}) to set [A, fileRef] to [the default application's path, it as alias]`.  Finally, `tell application A to open the fileRef` 

Comment: Your use of compound commands is quite impressive.  However, the issue is that he wants every type of file, whether it's name extension is .scpt, .txt, .py, no extension, etc... all to be opened by the same app (Visual Studio Code.app).  Your solution uses the default application for each specific name extension, to open the file.  I am open to better solutions but as for right now, I still think my solution handles the task pretty seamlessly.  No?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on doing file activities with the Finder it is best to avoid using posix paths. You have a couple of redundancies in your code so I streamlined it a bit.

```
set file_name to display dialog "File Name" default answer "untitled" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"
set file_name to (text returned of file_name)

tell application "Finder"
    set theWin to window 1
    set currentDir to (target of theWin as text)
    --> "MacHD:Users:username:Hours of Operation:"

    make new file at theWin with properties {name:file_name}
    set currentPath to currentDir & file_name
    --> "MacHD:Users:username:Hours of Operation:untitled.txt"
    open file currentPath
end tell
```

Try putting this after the above (and commenting out the above `open file…` line).

```
tell application "System Events"
    activate application "TextEdit"
    open file currentPath of application "TextEdit" 
end tell
currentPath
```

Also, after trying the above, put the variable name currentPath as the last line of the script (as I added above) and run from Script Editor. Its value should appear in the 'Result'. You can replace the drive/username components but I want to see the exact layout of the string.

A couple of things to consider:

Some files can't be opened this way, for example, a jpeg. Preview will balk at opening an empty image, presumably because that's not how images are made. Complex file formats (e.g. pages) will also fail. But with a plain text file, there shouldn't be any issues. As such, I'd consider adding '.txt' to your default filename.

Comment: Thanks Mockman. This is one step closer, but I get a permission error instead. The script already has root privilege and I can open the file - it just wont open from applescript

Comment: What version of the OS?

Comment: I'm using montery (12.6)

Comment: Monterey has some security concerns that affect some actions. Are you running the script from Script Editor or as an application? You may need to give accessibility permissions (in Security & Privacy in System Preferences). I'm using a much older OS (Sierra) so I'm not up to speed on these.